# Difference between 'on :resource_updated' and 'on :resource_completed' in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I use Chef.event_handler to intercept running resources in order to generate a chef run report.
In the recope I use chef resources and my custom resources. Some of the resources are handled by ':resource_updated', but others do not.

For that reason I write this:

```
Chef.event_handler do
  processed_declared_types = Set.new
  on :resource_updated do |resource|
      ReportLogger::Logger.resource_updated(resource)
      processed_declared_types.add(resource.declared_type)
    end
  end

  on :resource_completed do |resource|
    if !processed_declared_types.include?(resource.declared_type)
      ReportLogger::Logger.resource_updated(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

What is the difference between 'on :resource_updated' and 'on :resource_completed'?
Why are some resources caught by one event type but others not?